# 3 select boxes but one value based off the choices of all 3

Tags: javascript

I am making an insurance form for glasses and the first select box is the insurance plan.  The second select box is the style of lens, and the third box is the options you want on the lens.  Is there a way to pick from 3 insurance plans and then choose the lens style and then pick an option and have the amount put into a input box for before insurance and another input box for after insurance.  The value will be based off the options on the last select, but different amounts based on Plan and lens style?

Was thinking of this:

```
<select>
<option>Plan A</option>
<option>Plan B</option>
<option>Plan C</option>
</select>

<select>
<option>Single Vision</option>
<option>Bifocal</option>
<option>Trifocal</option>
<option>Progressive</option>
</select>

<select id="options1">
<option>Anti-Glare Coating</option>
<option>Transitions</option>
<option>Edge Polish</option>
<option>Sunglass Tint</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="before1" class="before">
<input type="text" id="after1" class="after">
```

Well, if you choose "Plan A" in a drop down, and then choose single vision in another drop down, the options would cost:

```
<select id="options1">
<option value="140,85">Anti-Glare Coating</option>
<option value="100,76">Transitions</option>
<option value="16,9">Edge Polish</option>
<option value="36,15">Sunglass Tint</option>
</select>
```

But if you chose Plan B, Progressives, the cost for the same options would change becuase of the first two choices. Hope this helps clarify.  I guess I am looking to change the value of the options on lenses based on the first two select boxes. :-)

Comment: Can you clarify the requirement? It's kinda confusing. Are you talking about connected dropdowns?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Please make a start and we will help when you get stuck. Start by giving the options a value attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object that shows the price for each option:

```
var prices = {
    'Plan A': {
        'Single Vision': {
            'Anti-Glare Coating': {
                before: 100,
                after: 50
            },
            'Transitions': {
                before: 80,
                after: 60
            },
            ...
        },
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

Then after the user selects from the menus, get the values and use them as indexes into the object:

```
var plan = document.getElementById("plan").value;
var type = document.getElementById("type").value;
var option = document.getElementById("options1").value;
document.getElementById("before1").value = prices[plan][type][option].before;
document.getElementById("after1").value = prices[plan][type][option].after;
```

In a real application you wouldn't hard-code the object like that, you can get it from a database using AJAX.